# 404 error when accessing WCF Rest service hosted in ASP.net on Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a WCF Rest Server hosted in an ASP.net Application.  It was set up using the simple RouteTable setup in global.asax.  ON my development machine with IIS 7, it works perfectly, but when I deployed to A windows Server 2008 machine with similar IIS settings, it does not work, I get a 404 error when my ajax methods tries to access the service.  I was wondering if WCF is able to be hosted like I have on my development machine on an actual production server?  If so what must I do to get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried to browse the service from IIS after hosting on Win Server 2008

Comment: I am able to access the asp.net portion of the site hosted, but when I get to the page that accesses the service via ajax, it returns 404.  Also accessing the help pages for the service returns 404.

Answer (score 0):

turns out from careful googling it turned out to be a missing attribute on  system.webserver modules section: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Source:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Mar/27/ASPNET-Routing-not-working-on-IIS-70

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was even more simple!

The symptom was that all POST requests returned 404s.

I'd only just enabled IIS (via Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on and off) on a new Dev machine that already had Visual Studio fully installed.

I had to enable .NET 4.5 for IIS (via `C:\\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`) and then all was well.

It's confusing, because I had already set the IIS App Pool to run under .NET Framework v4.0.30319. There was no warning that I had to separately run regiis.